# Selecting directory by browse button

Tags: python, python-3.x, directory, path

I am working on a simple Rename program but I'm facing two problems:

1. if I add a new Button for "Browse" to select a folder I get some errors.
2. if I run program the folder selection window shows up automatically but I want to run it every time I click on the button.

The problem is I can make a button and it also can browse and select folders
but how can I bind it to my working path without getting errors? I guess there is some problems with the

```
list = os.listdir(path) 
os.chdir(path)
```

full code is :

```
import os
from tkinter import *
#from PIL import ImageTk,Image
from tkinter import filedialog

window = Tk()
window.title("Rename Helper")
window.geometry("500x302")
window.resizable(width = False , height = False)
#window.iconbitmap('licon.ico')

#canvas = Canvas(window)
#image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open('Rename.png'))
#canvas.create_image(0, 0, anchor=NW, image=image)
#canvas.place( height=500, width=500)

hl_text = StringVar()
e1 = Entry(window, textvariable=hl_text)
e1.place(height=22, width=100, x= 280, y=140)

d_text = StringVar()
e2 = Entry(window, textvariable=d_text)
e2.place(height=22, width=100, x= 280, y=192)

fileExt = (".png", ".jpg", ".jpeg", ".PNG", "JPG", ".JPEG")
def rename(path, new_name, numbering, d_text, extension,):
    list = os.listdir(path)
    os.chdir(path)
    count = numbering
    for i in list:
        if i.endswith(fileExt):
            os.rename(i, new_name + "_P_" + str(count).zfill(2) + "_" + d_text + '.' + extension)
            count += 1

path = filedialog.askdirectory()

def renamebtn():
    newname = hl_text.get()
    newdate = d_text.get()
    rename(path, newname, 1, newdate, "jpg")

btn1 = Button(window, text="Rename", command=renamebtn)
btn1.place(height=50, width=200, x= 280, y=235)

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Do include the error code too

Comment: The code you posted doesn't include a "Browse" button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why it runs automatically is because your calling the function (using `()`), to fix this just assign a button like you would do with normal functions and put path inside of it. Like:

```py
btn2 = Button(window,text='Choose',command=choose)
btn2.pack() # or even place, depending on what you used previously
```

Then the function would be like:

```py
def choose():
    global path
    path = filedialog.askdirectory()
```

This would will make the `filedialog` pop up only when you click the button.

If any doubts or errors, do let me know

Cheers